# How to show child page without providing ID so it's dynamic

Tags: child-pages

[image]

So this is my code. This piece of code shows me the child page titles.
But i'm providing the ID from the parent page. Is there a way to make this dynamic? I don't want to use the ID cuz then its static..

```
  <?php
                  $childArgs = array(
                      'sort_order' => 'ASC',
                      'sort_column' => 'menu_order',
                      'child_of' => 127
                  );
                  $childList = get_pages($childArgs);
                  foreach ($childList as $child) { ?>

        <ul class="menu-items menu-level-1 menu-count-5">
          <li class="menu-item item-number-1  item-number-2 item-number-3 item-number-4 item-number-5 item-id-84283 item-odd item-page item-node item-alias-over-ons-de-winkel"><a href=""><?php echo $child->post_title; ?></a></li>
        <?php } ?>
```

Comment: Can you clarify on what exactly you want to achieve? Do you need to show *all* child pages? Child pages of a specific page? On the page you are browsing?

Comment: Hi, I have an About page as Parent page. And some child pages linked to the parent page. So on that about page i'm currently echo'ing the title. But lets say I make a new page and make it a parent then that won't work because im using ID from the first parent page (about). U see the problem?  So how can i make this dynamic? Thanks for helping me.. @Pim

Comment: If you're on the page that you want to retrieve children of: Use `get_the_ID()` instead of `127`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

//The correct code

functions.php

```
  function get_page_parent_id( $id ) {
$args = array(
  'sort_order' => 'ASC',
  'sort_column' => 'menu_order',
  'child_of' => $id
);
$args = get_pages($args);

if(is_array($pages))
  $pageID = $id;
else {
  $pageID = wp_get_post_parent_id( $id );
}

return $pageID;


}
 ?>
```

page.php

```
<?php
          $parentID = get_page_parent_id(get_the_ID());

            $childArgs = array(
            'sort_order' => 'ASC',
            'sort_column' => 'menu_order',
            'child_of' => $parentID
          ); ?>
    <div class="subnav">
      <h3 class="subnav-headline"><a href="/over-ons" class="c-dark"><?php echo get_the_title($parentID); ?></a></h3>

        <ul class="menu-items menu-level-1 menu-count-5">
             <?php $pages = get_pages($childArgs);
                foreach($pages as $page ) { ?>
          <li class="menu-item item-number-2 item-id-84286 item-even item-page item-node item-alias-over-ons-geschiedenis-leonidas"><a href="<?php echo get_the_permalink($page);?>"><?php echo $page->post_title;?></a></li>
            <?php   }   ?>
      </ul>
    </div>
```

Answer (score -1):

Try the following:

```
<?php

  global $post;

  $page_id = get_the_id();

  $childArgs = array(
    'sort_order' => 'ASC',
    'sort_column' => 'menu_order',
    'child_of' => $page_id
  );
  $childList = get_pages($childArgs);

  if($childList && (!$post->post_parent || is_page(127))){ ?>
    <ul class="menu-items menu-level-1 menu-count-5">
      <?php foreach ($childList as $child) { ?>
        <li class="menu-item item-number-1  item-number-2 item-number-3 item-number-4 item-number-5 item-id-84283 item-odd item-page item-node item-alias-over-ons-de-winkel">
          <a href=""><?php echo $child->post_title; ?></a>
        </li>
      <?php } ?>
    </ul>
  <?php } ?>
```